# Maintain session in command line [PYTHON]

Tags: python, session, request, flask

I am currently working with python and flask framework.
I have one python class with different methods. I have a module that is responsible for maintaining session stuffs. My program flow is like sequential(multiple requests one after another meaning that second request is due to the first one.) request-response format.

My problem is, whenever a request is made to the server, last session is destroyed and new session instance is created while making request from command line.

Is there any session-key or something like that? How server knows the client request is of last established session?

[EDIT]
Here is code snippet:

```
 def second_request():
    if session['first']:
        return True

    return False

class Test():
    def operate(self,):
        if second_request():
            #increase loggedin count by one for session['user'] or something like that    
            return True
        else:
            self.set_first()
            return False

    def set_first(self, ):
        session['first'] = True
```

I want to call(from terminal) operate method of Test class and that will go in if loop.

Comment: *while making request from command line*. Do you mean you use something like `curl` to make the requests? Sessions use cookies, if the client doesn't handle cookies then no session is preserved.

Comment: You need to show us more details as to what you are doing here; specifically the command line.

Comment: Ok I will add code snippet to the question itself.

Comment: Maybe look at the problem from different angle: for what do you need to hit your app from command line? I cannot imagine when cmd stuff like curl/wget will help you programming flask application. If you need to test you app, then use regular flask TestClient, which handles cookies/sessions properly..

Comment: @StanislavHeller: Yes, one of the requirements is testing too. But major thing is I want to expose some apis which can be access by users without my GUI.

Comment: from the command line you will need to append a token to each request if you do not want to use cookies this is the only way for a web server to know its your session

Comment: @JoeDoherty: Token means? Main thing that I am willing to know is the session identity value.

Comment: You could append it to the URL as in something.com/api/post?token=<SESSION ID> this would at least allow the stateless web application to know what session you are.

Comment: I am sorry but how can I get that <SESSION ID>?